# org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool - Unable to create initial connections of pool with yml file

Tags: java, tomcat, grails, yaml

sorry for the long error log. I'm at my wits end, im upgrading an old app from 2.2.2 to 3.1.2 and i really need help.

tried to apply datasource.groovy to application.yml

```
hibernate:
cache:
    queries: false
    use_second_level_cache: true
    use_query_cache: false
    region.factory_class: 'org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory'

dataSource:
pooled: true
jmxExport: true
driverClassName: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
username: root
password: root

environments:
development:
    dataSource:
        dbCreate: update
        url: jdbc:h2:mem:devDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000
test:
    dataSource:
        driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
        username: sa
        password:
        dbCreate: update
        url: jdbc:h2:mem:testDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
production:
    dataSource:
        dbCreate: update
        url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db
        pooled: true
        properties:
            jmxEnabled: true
            initialSize: 5
            maxActive: 50
            minIdle: 5
            maxIdle: 25
            maxWait: 10000
            maxAge: 600000
            timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis: 5000
            minEvictableIdleTimeMillis: 60000
            validationQuery: SELECT 1
            validationQueryTimeout: 3
            validationInterval: 15000
            testOnBorrow: true
            testWhileIdle: true
            testOnReturn: false
            jdbcInterceptors: ConnectionState
            defaultTransactionIsolation: 2 # TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED
```

after doing so, run-app doesn't work and these are what appeared amongst others. any help will be greatly appreciated.

This is what's been happening so far

```
ERROR org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool - Unable to create initial connections of pool.
java.sql.SQLException: Unable to load class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver from ClassLoader:sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@14dad5dc;ClassLoader:sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@14dad5dc
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:280) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.0.30.jar:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:200) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.0.30.jar:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:708) [tomcat-jdbc-8.0.30.jar:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:642) [tomcat-jdbc-8.0.30.jar:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:464) [tomcat-jdbc-8.0.30.jar:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:141) [tomcat-jdbc-8.0.30.jar:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:115) [tomcat-jdbc-8.0.30.jar:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:102) [tomcat-jdbc-8.0.30.jar:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:126) [tomcat-jdbc-8.0.30.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy$LazyConnectionInvocationHandler.getTargetConnection(LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy.java:403) [spring-jdbc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy$LazyConnectionInvocationHandler.invoke(LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy.java:376) [spring-jdbc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy55.getMetaData(Unknown Source) [na:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
        at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1426) [springloaded-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar:1.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy$TransactionAwareInvocationHandler.invoke(TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy.java:240) [spring-jdbc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy55.getMetaData(Unknown Source) [na:na]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:126) [hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:111) [hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234) [hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206) [hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1887) [hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1845) [hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.HibernateMappingContextConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(HibernateMappingContextConfiguration.java:196) [grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate4-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateMappingContextSessionFactoryBean.doBuildSessionFactory(HibernateMappingContextSessionFactoryBean.java:476) [grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate4-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateMappingContextSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(HibernateMappingContextSessionFactoryBean.java:470) [grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate4-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateMappingContextSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(HibernateMappingContextSessionFactoryBean.java:93) [grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate4-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637) [spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574) [spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) [spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) [spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) [spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) [spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) [spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) [spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351) [spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108) [spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1481) [spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1226) [spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543) [spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) [spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) [spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) [spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) [spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) [spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.grails.transaction.TransactionManagerPostProcessor.initialize(TransactionManagerPostProcessor.java:75) [grails-core-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
        at org.grails.transaction.TransactionManagerPostProcessor.setBeanFactory(TransactionManagerPostProcessor.java:53) [grails-core-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeAwareMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1597) [spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1565) [spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) [spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) [spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) [spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) [spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) [spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) [spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:207) [spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:687) [spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:523) [spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) [spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766) [spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361) [spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) [spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:55) [grails-core-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:365) [grails-core-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:354) [grails-core-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp$run.call(Unknown Source) [grails-core-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48) [groovy-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113) [groovy-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133) [groovy-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
        at grailsapp.Application.main(Application.groovy:8) [main/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Unable to load class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver from ClassLoader:sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@14dad5dc;ClassLoader:sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@14dad5dc
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ClassLoaderUtil.loadClass(ClassLoaderUtil.java:56) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.0.30.jar:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:268) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.0.30.jar:na]
        ... 71 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ClassLoaderUtil.loadClass(ClassLoaderUtil.java:38) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.0.30.jar:na]
        ... 72 common frames omitted
ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application startup failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:207) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:687) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:523) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766) ~[spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361) ~[spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) ~[spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:55) [grails-core-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:365) [grails-core-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:354) [grails-core-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp$run.call(Unknown Source) [grails-core-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48) [groovy-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113) [groovy-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133) [groovy-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
        at grailsapp.Application.main(Application.groovy:8) [main/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1481) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1226) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.grails.transaction.TransactionManagerPostProcessor.initialize(TransactionManagerPostProcessor.java:75) ~[grails-core-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
        at org.grails.transaction.TransactionManagerPostProcessor.setBeanFactory(TransactionManagerPostProcessor.java:53) ~[grails-core-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeAwareMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1597) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1565) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        ... 34 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:244) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:111) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1887) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1845) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.HibernateMappingContextConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(HibernateMappingContextConfiguration.java:196) ~[grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate4-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateMappingContextSessionFactoryBean.doBuildSessionFactory(HibernateMappingContextSessionFactoryBean.java:476) ~[grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate4-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateMappingContextSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(HibernateMappingContextSessionFactoryBean.java:470) ~[grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate4-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateMappingContextSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(HibernateMappingContextSessionFactoryBean.java:93) ~[grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate4-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        ... 41 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Hmm, it looks like you're missing the MySQL JDBC dependency. You probably need a dependency in build.gradle, something like this: `compile 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.38'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edited build.gradle file to include

```
runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.36'
```

This has solved the connection issue with Mysql

Answer (score 0):

Where is username and password?
Here is an example from my app.

```
dataSource:
dbCreate: create-drop
driverClassName: "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
dialect: "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"
url: "jdbc:mysql://localhost/blaapps?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8"
username: "myuser"
password: "mypassword"
properties:
    jmxEnabled: true
    initialSize: 5
    maxActive: 50
    minIdle: 5
    maxIdle: 25
    maxWait: 10000
    maxAge: 600000
    timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis: 5000
    minEvictableIdleTimeMillis: 60000
    validationQuery: SELECT 1
    validationQueryTimeout: 3
    validationInterval: 15000
    testOnBorrow: true
    testWhileIdle: true
    testOnReturn: false
    jdbcInterceptors: ConnectionState
    defaultTransactionIsolation: 2 # TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED
```

Comment: Also make sure in build.gradle you have
    runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.36'

Comment: username and password is really root root

Comment: If you have all that and still doesn't work. It means there is something else wrong. Either with DB or grails installation. For Grails installation I would rename ".grails" directory and let it to download all dependencies again.

Answer (score 0):

I also got this issue with Spring version of **"1.5.10.RELEASE"**.
When i decrease the version **"1.5.9.RELEASE"**. My problem has been solved.